# Behaviour and Order of evaluation in C#

Tags: c#, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Order of function evaluation (vs C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215236/c-order-of-function-evaluation-vs-c)

Code snippet:

```
i += ++i;
a[++i] = i;
int result =  fun() - gun();
//statement of similar kind
```

Are their behavior well-defined in C#? In C++, such code invokes [undefined/unspecified behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded). Please also quote the relevant sections from the language specification in your response!

Comment: Is there any aspect of your question not answered by various people in [C#: Order of function evaluation (vs C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215236/c-order-of-function-evaluation-vs-c)?

Comment: @Gabe : the first two statements in my question is slightly different than what is discussed in the other topic. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: @All : please don't vote for closing this topic. there is no harm if I get some answer to first two statements in my question.

Comment: I believe [Pavel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215236/c-order-of-function-evaluation-vs-c/1215257#1215257) quotes the proper section of the spec to answer all of your questions.

Comment: @Gabe : it looks like. But leppie has some doubts there.

Comment: It's not like this is hard to find in the specification. Hint: check the table of contents.

Comment: If this subject interests you, you might also see my articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/precedence/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is the table in "1.4 Expressions", and "7.3.1 Operator precedence and associativity". I won't duplicate the table from 1.4, but to quote 7.3.1:

> - Except for the assignment operators,
>     all binary operators are
>     left-associative, meaning that
>     operations are performed from left to
>     right. For example, x + y + z is
>     evaluated as (x + y) + z.
> - The
>     assignment operators and the
>     conditional operator (?:) are
>     right-associative, meaning that
>     operations are performed from right to
>     left. For example, x = y = z is
>     evaluated as x = (y = z).

The first is *logically* expanded (or: use the associativity rules) as:

```
i = i + ++i;
```

here, the order (from the table) is pre-increment, then additive, then assignment - so we should expect i to double plus one. And indeed, with `i=6`, we get 13 as expected.

```
a[++i] = i;
```

again from the table, order should be array access, pre-increment, assignment - so I would expect the i+1'th value to be i+1. And indeed, checking:

```
    int[] a = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int i = 2;
    a[++i] = i;
```

we do indeed get `{0, 0, 0, 3, 0}`.

With the last, method invocation takes priority over subtraction, then it is left-to-right; so it should be `fun()`, `gun()`, `-`, assignment.

Comment: Or `gun(), fun(), -, assignment`

Comment: @leppie - left associative, surely (section 7.3.1)

Comment: But only on the values, hence after they have been evaluated (method invoked). In general, it is left to right, but I dont see any guarantees.

Comment: I think there's one more sentence that needs to be quoted from the spec: `The order of evaluation of operators in an expression is determined by the precedence and associativity of the operators.`  *In general*, precendence and associativity don't necessarily determine the order of evaluation (C being one example where `x + y + z` = `(x + y) + z`, but the order of evaluation is undefined).

Comment: 7.4.1 actually covers this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691335, it has nothing to do with operators. They seems to 'guarantee' it, but still say the compiler is free to rearrange the execution if it can prove there are no side effects. Not much of a guarantee in that case  ;P

Answer (score 11):

People always get this so confused, which is unfortunate because in C# it is extremely straightforward. The rules are:

- subexpressions are observed to be evaluated *left to right* when observed from the executing thread, period, end of story. (Order of evaluation is permitted to be observed to be different by some other thread if some other thread is watching the side effects.)
- the order in which the operators execute is determined by their precedence and associativity.

Those are the only two relevant rules, and they completely define the behaviour of the code you give. In

```
i += ++i;
```

first i is evaluated, then ++i is evaluated, and then the += is executed.

```
a[++i] = i;
```

First 'a' is evaluated, then ++i is evaluated, then the indexing operator runs, then i is evaluated, then the assignment happens.

```
int result =  fun() - gun();
```

first result is evaluated, then fun, then gun, then the subtraction, then the assignment.

> Please also quote the relevant sections from the language specification in your response!

You are perfectly capable of looking in the table of contents. It's not hard to find.

Comment: @leppie: I am extremely confused by your question. How else would you know where to store the value produced by the right side if you didn't *evaluate* the left hand side of the assignment and from it produce a *variable*?

Comment: Now I am also confused :)  Let me rephrase; why does a local slot declaration (aka `result`) need to be evaluated? It contains no meaningful (or usable) value before initialization (iow first assignment).

Comment: @leppie: It is not being evaluated for the *contents* of the variable, it's being evaluated for the *location*. The contents are irrelevant, but how are you going to figure out the location for the assignment without evaluating the left hand side? My point is that the evaluation of the left hand side happens *before* the right hand side: **in C# the subexpressions are always evaluated left to right** and that includes subexpressions such as local variables being evaluated to determine their addresses.

Comment: @leppie: Maybe this would make you feel better. In "A().B().C[D()].E = F();" the evaluation of field E has to happen before the evaluation of function call F(). In order to evaluate field E to determine its location, we must first evaluate A(), B(), C(), D() and execute the index operator. **The left hand side of the assignment is evaluated before the right hand side**. It is evaluated to determine the *location* that the right hand side is going to be assigned to.