# are the parameters in a function executed sequentially?

Tags: c#

in C# if I have function that prints the two values it gets assumed its called print...
in the following case what is the output

```
int i=0;
public int current_I(){return i;}
public int next_I(){return ++i;}
//---------
print(next_I(),current_I());
```

in other words can we know which function will execute first {current_I or next_I} or its just like the C++ we can never know the sequence of execution of the parameters ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215236/c-order-of-function-evaluation-vs-c ?

Comment: What did you get when you ran this code ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, OP will get two 1s, I can only guess what the `print` function does ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Function parameters are evaluated strictly left-to-right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691335).

Look for the line

> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (Section 7.4.3), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right, as follows:

above the third set of bullet points.